# Upgraded Postgres; how to access old, missing databases?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

My local connection on my Mac (10.9.5) wasn't working to my Postgres (9.3) database, so I tried upgrading it to 9.4. Luckily I can now connect to the database, but... My old databases (and tables, views, etc.) are now missing...

Is it possible to recover these? How would I go about doing that?

Comment: there is lots of documentation about postgres upgrades on the web. do you have a problem with anything in particular?

Comment: Yes, the upgrade is fine, and I can now connect to the new version. The data, however, is missing. I am not sure how (or where) to find the data that was previously in the database.

Comment: Maybe someone on http://dba.stackexchange.com can help you. Ask there.

Comment: You upgraded from a non-working situation to a ... non-working situation. What did you do exactly? How could we know?. (BTW: I hope you have a backup)

Comment: It wasn't possible to export a backup, because the database wouldn't connect... I do believe I have backups, but I'm trying to figure out if I can reconnect to the old databases/tables without having to load all the data again.

Comment: A 9.4 server won't use a 9.3 datadir. The 9.3 server must be started first to access the 9.3 data. If it can't start, it will report with error messages in a server log file whose location depends on what postgresql flavor you installed, like homebrew or postgres.app or macports or others.